# Build NodeJS back-end with dependencies for NWJS desktop application

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, nestjs, nwjs

I have an application that is built with angular (FE), and Nestjs (BE).
The application is working fine on the server.

I am trying to combine the application with NWJS environment in order to create a desktop application.

I can run the application coping FE build code and BE build code + node_modules to a folder in the NWJS environment.

Now I need to build the BE including dependencies (NestJS, xml2json etc) to a single server.js file so that I do not need to copy the node_modules folder to NWJS environment to work the application.

I tried to build with Webpack but the tool says

> the request of a dependency is an expression', 'Module not found:
>
> Error: Can't resolve 'pino-pretty' in ...

when running the Webpack command.

Is there any way to configure Webpack to build a single server.js file for NodeJS back-end application alone with its dependencies

or

any other build tool that can be suggested to achieve this task with an example would be highly appreciated.

[NWJS](https://nwjs.io/)

[NestJS](https://nestjs.com/)

Thank you

Comment: Webpack is a good way to do it. Could you please provide small and reproductible example of your facing issue ?

Comment: @Yanis-git, Here are the good examples that can combine and make the communications compile the src to a single JS file for FE and BE and build the desktop application to run the app locally.

01. https://github.com/nwutils/nw-angular-cli-example
02. https://github.com/nwutils/nw-local-server-example

Comment: Sorry for this miss understood, we need to have a minimal and reproductible example of your code, where we can reproduce `Error: Can't resolve 'pino-pretty' in ...` then we will be able to dig and find why your are facing this error.

Comment: @Yanis-git, I will provide it shortly, Thank you very much